# Conflict with Superclass property name and Protocol method name

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working with the GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and want to implement a Class which inherits the baseclass GPUImageOutput and realize the protocoll GPUImageInput.

Get the Error:
Method 'shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget()' with Objective-C selector 'shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget' conflicts with getter for 'shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget' from superclass 'GPUImageOutput' with the same Objective-C selector

Is there a workaround for this issue in Swift?

The only solution I have is:
Implement a Obj-C "dummy base class" and inherit form them in Swift?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redeclaring the property from the base class with a different getter:

```
@property(readwrite, nonatomic, getter=superclass_shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget) BOOL shouldIgnoreUpdatesToThisTarget;
```